# How to work with Excel sheet data in an VBA array and then paste back into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 'master data' spreadsheet that is 81MB. I've currently got a macro in it that copies all the data (47791 rows and 76 columns) and pastes it as values into a template (another 37MB spreadsheet) that then has further columns in it that have formulas to calculate pricing info.

My current code is below, but it's manipulating the data INSIDE the spreadsheet, and the macro takes 15 minutes to run...

I think that if VBA could load all of the data into memory, and then do the filter and the sorts whilst it's in memory, before them pasting it into the other spreadsheet, it would be much quicker. Hopefully that's correct?

```
Sub CreateDailySheet()

'Filter for out rows at the bottom only containing #value! errors, and select all
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array _
        ("DA", "DB", "E1", "E2", "FF", "FG", "G1", "GA", "GS", "I0", "I2", "IK", "IX"), Operator _
        :=xlFilterValues
    Range("MAIN").Select
    
'Open template
    Workbooks.Open "O:\GLOBAL\JACK\Pricing\Trial\Templates\DERIVED TEMPLATE.xlsx"
    
'Copy data
    Windows("MASTER DATA (DERIVED).xlsm").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    
'Paste into template
    Windows("DERIVED TEMPLATE.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Sort template
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[RIM]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[PROFILE]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[SECTION]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[LOAD & SPEED INDEX]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[PRODUCT GROUP]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
'Save template as new daily spreadsheet with todays date
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "O:\GLOBAL\JACK\Pricing\Trial\DERIVED " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") & ".XLSX", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Close this new spreadsheet and unfilter the data sheet
    ActiveWindow.Close
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7

End Sub
```

I've loaded the data into an array (I think), as below, but I'm unsure how to filter out the bottom rows that have errors (in column 3, say), how to sort the data by the 5 columns done in the origin macro, and how to then add it back into the template spreadsheet.

```
Dim dataArr As Variant
dataArr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
```

Comment: Filtering and sorting is easier when done on the worksheet, particularly if you're not that comfortable in VBA.  What might help with your execution speed is setting ScreenUpdating to False and Calculation to manual, so those don't slow down the run.

Comment: I actually am doing that I just removed it for the sake of space here, however it wasn't a noticable improvement at all. It stayed around 14 minutes. Hopefully doing it in computer memory would reduce that significantly, so I'd rather not give up so quickly.

Comment: @JackShone what kind of errors do you have in column 3? Do you want to filter the rows with errors in?

Comment: How long does it take to run without the sorting ?

Comment: I want to REMOVE the #VALUE! errors, not keep them, apologies if unclear.

I can't get rid of them before this point, unfortunately. I've tried that one already.

Comment: @JackShone and you are trying to read data from "MAIN" worksheet or "D0-FZ" ?

Comment: actually seems to only take 2 minutes without the sort. So maybe only VBA code or the sort would be useful, nevermind the filter... I definitely do still need a solution, as taking the sort out of the macro only means that the 12 remaining minutes will be spent doing the sort manually... which is even worse.

Comment: From MAIN and the end product is pasted into D0-FZ.

Comment: 2 mins seems long for copy/paste, is the file on a network drive ?

Comment: Yes, it's for use by multiple people. and the original spreadsheet pulls data from multiple CSV's and the 2nd spreadsheet is linked to other spreadsheets. I know it will always be relatively slow, that's no problem.  I'm just sure that working with the data in memory would be quicker than directly in excel, no?

Comment: @JackShone see if the code below that i added in my Answer helps you and speeds things up.

Comment: You could try opening the template from the C: drive and still save to O: ie `Workbooks.Open "c:\some folder\DERIVED TEMPLATE.xls"`

Comment: I will try using the c drive tomorrow when back in the office. However the opening part only takes around 20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the code Shia. I’m try it tomorrow morning in the office. Would sorting also be possible in the array or is that no use?

Comment: @JackShone you can sort within the array as well

Comment: If interested, check out [How to make your Excel VBA code run 1000 times faster](https://youtu.be/GCSF5tq7pZ0?si=_dJ1JAxXxTuc_uOG) on Excel Macro Mastery’s YouTube channel… Advanced Filter might help speed things up (then sort the results, as needed).

Comment: That guy is brilliant! I just implemented his class modules for sorting and my macro is already running in 2 minutes instead of 15. I'll add in the filter and I'm done. thanks @DjC.

Comment: Great! I just posted a solution using the Advanced Filter method. Compare it, if you wish, to see if there's any difference. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advanced Filter** would be an ideal solution for your situation.

The `.AutoFilter` and `.Sort` methods in your current code are likely the two main causes of the slow performance, considering the tables you are filtering and sorting contain calculated columns with many records. There's also a few other things that can be improved, though, like eliminating the use of `.Select` and `.Activate`, as well as `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` etc.

Since I'm not entirely sure what your data looks like, I'll demonstrate the `.AdvancedFilter` method with the sample data shown below:

[image: sample_data.png]

**(1)** First, insert a new sheet in your main workbook and rename it "*AdvFilter*".

**(2)** In cell `A1`, type the name of the column header that you want to filter by, which in this example is "Group" (in your original code, I can see it's column 7 from your "MAIN" table, but I'm not sure what it's called).

**(3)** In cell `A2`, type the criteria to filter by "Group". Since the main objective here is to remove records with `#VALUE!` errors, and since your "Group" codes only consist of text strings two characters long, use two question marks (??) for the criteria. (Note: a single asterisk (*) would also work, to return all records containing a text string of any length.)

**(4)** In row 5, starting in cell `A5`, type the header names of all the columns you wish to return from the "MAIN" table, in the order you wish to return them.

The final setup of the "*AdvFilter*" sheet should look something like this:

[image: advfilter_setup.png]

**(5)** Lastly, use the following code to achieve the desired results:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDailySheet()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Turn off application settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Filter MAIN table and output results to AdvFilter sheet
    Dim wsFilter As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, rg As Range
    Set wsFilter = Sheets("AdvFilter")
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set rg = ws.ListObjects("MAIN").Range
    Call AdvFilter(rg, wsFilter.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, wsFilter.Range("A5"))

'Re-enable MAIN table filters, which were disabled by Advanced Filter
    rg.AutoFilter

'Sort the results by the desired columns
    Dim rgResults As Range
    Set rg = wsFilter.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
    Set rgResults = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1)
    With wsFilter.Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add2 Key:=rgResults.Columns(1)
        .Add2 Key:=rgResults.Columns(5), Order:=xlDescending
        .Add2 Key:=rgResults.Columns(2)
        .Add2 Key:=rgResults.Columns(6)
        .Add2 Key:=rgResults.Columns(3), Order:=xlDescending
    End With
    With wsFilter.Sort
        .SetRange rg
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

'Copy the results to an array
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = rgResults.Value

'Open the template workbook and write the results to the destination range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("O:\GLOBAL\JACK\Pricing\Trial\Templates\DERIVED TEMPLATE.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("D0-FZ")
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

'Save and close the new daily workbook
    Dim str As String
    str = "O:\GLOBAL\JACK\Pricing\Trial\DERIVED " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") & ".xlsx"
    wb.SaveAs str, 51 'xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next

'Turn on application settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Runtime Error: " & Err.Number
    Err.Clear
    GoTo CleanUp

End Sub

Private Sub AdvFilter(sourceRng As Range, criteriaRng As Range, outputRng As Range, Optional optUnique As Boolean)
    
'Clear the previous search results
    outputRng.CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents

'Output the new search results
    On Error Resume Next
    sourceRng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteriaRng, outputRng.CurrentRegion, optUnique

End Sub
```

**Additional Notes:**

- Adjust the sheet names in the above code to match your data
- Adjust the sort columns in the above code, as desired
- When sorting, default settings can be omitted

Cheers!

Comment: Worked perfectly, took about 1 minute 50 seconds, and used native vba rather than what I tried before. Perfect answer @DjC, Thank you!

Comment: @JackShone Glad to hear it! One small thing you may want to add is to clear the AdvFilter results from your worksheet immediately after copying them to an array, in order to keep your master file size down (it’s already big enough, lol). So right after `arr = rgResults.Value` you could add `rgResults.ClearContents` if you want. ;-)

Comment: Already added it :) that's great.

Comment: Apart from the unnecessary `On Error Resume Next` at the cleanup, a clean solution. I believe I also understand AdvancedFilter a bit more now, thanks :)

Comment: @Notus_Panda Good catch! That was an oversight on my part from copying and pasting code from another workbook. It’s not necessary in this case, but not hurting anything either. Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've attached a code sample filtering a Large 2-D array out `#VALUE!` at the 3rd column of the 2-D array.
Review the code comments for details.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadFilterArray()


Dim i As Long, ArrIndex As Long, Col As Long
Dim MainSht As Worksheet, DOSht As Worksheet
Dim dataArr As Variant, tempArr As Variant, FiltDataArr As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' set-up wortsheet objects
Set MainSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN")
Set DOSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("D0-FZ")

dataArr = MainSht.UsedRange.Value

' resize 2nd array to size of 1st array
ReDim FiltDataArr(1 To UBound(dataArr, 1), 1 To UBound(dataArr, 2))

' --- loop over 1st 2-D array and filter out #Value ---
For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
    ' 1st trap any error
    If IsError(dataArr(i, 3)) Then
        
        ' - check that current error is NOT #VALUE! -
        If dataArr(i, 3) <> CVErr(xlErrValue) Then
            ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
            ' copy data for current row to new array
            For Col = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 2)
                FiltDataArr(ArrIndex, Col) = dataArr(i, Col)
            Next Col
        End If
    
    Else  ' No Error in cell --> add to 2-D array
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        ' copy data for current row to new array
        For Col = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 2)
            FiltDataArr(ArrIndex, Col) = dataArr(i, Col)
        Next Col
    End If
Next i

If ArrIndex > 1 Then
    ' ~~~ Nice TRICK to redim first Dimension of 2-D array ~~~
    tempArr = FiltDataArr
    ReDim FiltDataArr(1 To ArrIndex, 1 To UBound(FiltDataArr, 2))
    For i = 1 To ArrIndex
        For Col = 1 To UBound(FiltDataArr, 2)
            FiltDataArr(i, Col) = tempArr(i, Col)
        Next Col
    Next i
End If

' Paste the 2-D array to "D0-FZ" worksheet (cell A1)
DOSht.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(FiltDataArr, 1), UBound(FiltDataArr, 2)).Value = FiltDataArr


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```